# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError - ErrorActivity.onCreate()

Tags: android

I am new to android apps development, and for somehow I am getting errors in my playgoogle apps account.
can anyone explain which kind of error is this?

```
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: dk.danyal.kids.channel.ErrorActivity.getActionBar
    at dk.danyal.kids.channel.ErrorActivity.onCreate(ErrorActivity.java:19)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1670)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3695)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your application is for Android 3.0 or higher and you are running it on Android 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Your Project should target Android version 3.0 or above to use getActionBar() function.

Answer (score 0):

To have the ActionBar in older versions of Android, you can have a look at ActionBarSherlock (http://actionbarsherlock.com/). It uses the ActionBar when it is available, and falls back on a custom implementation if it isn't available.